# Converting post data to string

Tags: php

I'm writing a php program that will convert user input to a string and count the times each character is used, eventually for each word.  Does anyone know how to convert the post data to a string?  I was looking at [implode](https://www.daniweb.com/programming/web-development/threads/8158/array-to-string) and [count_chars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count-chars.php), but implode isn't converting to string like expected.  I'm not sure how to show the error that it is encountering to give more information. I'm running it and writing it in phpFiddle.  I'm not sure how to run it elsewhere.  Please give info on what could be wrong with implode, how to show errors in phpFiddle, or run this in a browser without phpFiddle.

```
<?php
     echo $_POST['value'];
     $post_string = implode($_POST);
     foreach (count_chars($post_string, 1) as $i => $val) {
         echo "there were $val instances of \"", chr($i) , "\" in the string. \n";
     }
?>
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="value">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: why it isn't working as expected? What you get? What you want? Please, add an example of $_POST structure and what you expect.

Comment: Having error checking enabled would have allowed you to see what the error was with `implode()`. If you're not going to output errors to the screen keep your error logs open where you can see them.

Comment: What is the error? Code seems to work fine, https://eval.in/563889. `Implode` doesn't require `glue`. (don't need to implode though if there is only 1 index)

Comment: I'm not sure how to turn on error checking.  I'm not that familiar with php.  I'm using phpfiddle.org to run it.  I used to know how to run php in any browser but don't know anymore.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for.... 
`implode("", $_POST)`

Answer (score 7):

Imploding PHP Arrays usually requires two arguments, delimiter, and array.

To convert the $_POST array into a string, you should be able to implode it using;

`implode('', $_POST);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  I had to pick one and the one above it was the same, and I read it first, so I picked that one.  It worked!!!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this is what you are looking for.

```html
<?php
if (isset ($_POST['value'])) {
    echo $_POST['value'] . "<br>";
}
$post_string = implode("", $_POST);
foreach (count_chars($post_string, 1) as $i => $val) {
    echo "There were $val instances of \"", chr($i) , "\" in the string. <br>";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="">
    <input type="text" name="value">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```